# Track user through Google Universal Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I want to track a user from my site, give an id to Google Analytics and later be able to see which pages that id visited and for how long did that id view the pages.

I've tried custom variables with the classic analytics

I tried enabling the User-ID feature in the Universal Analytics

None of these have given me what I want yet. Is there any way to accomplish this with the Universal Analytics?

**UPDATE**

This is a sample code with a user whose id is 2. I try to set the userid in different ways to see if at least in one way it shows.

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'domain.com', { 'userId': '2' });

  ga('set', '&uid', '2'); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.

  var dimensionValue = '2';
  ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);

  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: A custom variable is exactly what you want. If it's not giving you what you want then you either set it up wrong, or you don't understand the reports. Or both. But on a sidenote: In case you did not know, it is against Google's ToS to track user ids that are personally identifiable to the user. That includes ids that link to personally identifiable info within your own system.

Comment: @Crayon, that's what I thought, too, but apparently it's okay to store an anonymous ID that can be tied to backend data as long as Google can't make the connection between the id and data that personally identifies an individual. Such an approach has been suggested e.g. by Analytics evangelist Justin Cutroni and has been embraced in the GA blog. It seems an anonymous ID is not "other data which can be reasonably linked to such information by Google". Makes sense, too, else we couldn't store transaction ids (which by their very nature are tied to personal data that. Somebody ordered that).

Comment: I put my code on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Userid is a feature that stitches together sessions from authenticated users over multiple devices. It is not displayed in the interface and will not accomplish what you are after.

However you can set a custom dimension. You will either have to create segments (a PITA since you'd need a segment for each unique user) or you will have to create custom reports, as custom dimensions will not show in standard reports [1]. So codewise you're fine, if you need advice on custom report creation I'd guess that webmasters@stackexchange.org is more suited for that (since  this does not involve code).

However I do not think GA is really a suitable tool to track indidual users, it's designed to analyze aggregate data from many users and visits.

[1] at least not as primary dimension, you can set them as secondary dimension.